# Generic update with mapping in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm writing a CRUD app using Slick, and I want my update queries to only update a specific set of columns and I use `.map().update()` for that.
I have a function that returns a tuple of fields that can be updated in my table definition (`def writableFields`). And I have a funciton that returns a tuple of values to write there extracted from a case class.
It works fine, but it's annoying to create a repo and write the whole `update` function for every table. I want to create a generic form of this function, and make my table and it's companion object to extend some trait. But I cannot come up with correct type definitions.
Slick expects output of `map()` to be somehow compatible with the output of `update`. And I don't know how to make a generic type for tuples.

Is it even possible to accomplish? Or is there an alternative way to limit code duplication? Ideally I want to avoid writing Repos at all and just either instantiate a generic class or call a generic method.

```
object ProjectsRepo extends BaseRepository[Projects, Project] {
    protected val query = lifted.TableQuery[Projects]

    def update(id: Long, c: Project): Future[Option[Project]] = {
        val q = filterByIdQuery(id).map(_.writableFields)
          .update(Projects.mapFormToTable(c))
        (db run q).flatMap(
          affected =>
            if (affected > 0) {
              findOneById(id)
            } else {
              Future(None)
            }
        )
    }
}

class Projects(tag: Tag) extends Table[Project](tag, "projects") with IdentifiableTable[Long] {
    val id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    val title = column[String]("title")
    val slug = column[String]("slug")
    val created_at = column[Timestamp]("created_at")
    val updated_at = column[Timestamp]("updated_at")

    def writableFields =
        (
          title,
          slug
        )

    def readableFields =
        (
          id,
          created_at,
          updated_at
        )

    def allFields = writableFields ++ readableFields // shapeless

    def * = allFields <> (Projects.mapFromTable, (_: Project) => None)
}

object Projects {
    def mapFormToTable(c: Project): FormFields =
        (
          c.title,
          c.slug
        )
}
```